# How to edit the existing SQL table column values using GreenDao?

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I'm using greenDao for my Android project and I did not get any official documentation on how to update SQLite table using greenDao. I found some `.update()` method there to edit, but looks like it's not recommended.

Comment: What do you mean by update SQLite table? Update the values of the rows? O update the columns of the table?

Comment: Updating the values in populated SQL table

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code updating an entity. You don't have to modify the generated class.

```
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
ExampleDao exampleDao = daoSession.getExampleDao();
Example example = exampleDao.load(exampleKey);

/* Make your changes in the object */

exampleDao.update(example);
```

If you need more documentation you can have a look [here](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/) and [here](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/).